# Make a vector of sums of matrix rows

Tags: matrix, summation

I have a matrix in *Mathematica*:

```
W = {{Subscript[x, 11], Subscript[x, 12], Subscript[x, 13]},
    {Subscript[x, 21], Subscript[x, 22], Subscript[x, 23]},
    {Subscript[x, 31], Subscript[x, 32], Subscript[x, 33]}}
```

I would like to make a column vector (called `g`), where each row (i.e. each element) is the sum of the equivalent row in the matrix `W`.

My code for `g` is, at the moment:

```
g = {{Total[W[[1]]]}, {Total[W[[2]]]}, {Total[W[[3]]]}}
```

This is fine for this situation, where the matrix `W` only has a few rows. But if matrix `W` were giant, this wouldn't be a great approach, as I would need to index every single row in the matrix when defining `g`.

I'm new to *Mathematica*, so I thought that the answer might involve the `Do` function, for a matrix with a total of `A` rows...

```
Do[Subscript[g, i] = Total[W[[i]],{1,A}]
```

...but this doesn't seem to solve the issue.

I would be very grateful if anyone could point me in the right direction. I am sure this is a very simple question for all you *Mathematica* whizzes... ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
List@*Total /@ W
```

> [image]

```
% === g
```

$\ $ `True`

Answer (score 6):

```
List@*Total /@ W (V10 only)
List /@ Total /@ W (V10 or earlier)
(* {{Subscript[x, 11] + Subscript[x, 12] + Subscript[x, 13]}, 
    {Subscript[x, 21] + Subscript[x, 22] + Subscript[x, 23]}, 
    {Subscript[x, 31] + Subscript[x, 32] + Subscript[x, 33]}} *)
```

other alternatives:

```
List /@ Plus @@@ W
List /@ Total[W, {2}]
```

Comment: Those are very helpful alternatives, thank's Sjoerd. Sorry I'm not allowed to accept both answers!

Comment: @sprog Luckily, you can vote for both. ;-)

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I will do that :)

Comment: Aha! I have done! It will show when I have more reputation.

Answer (score 5):

Algebra approach. `Dot` `W`with a column vector of 1's.

```
W . ConstantArray[1, {Last@Dimensions@W, 1}]
```

---

Was just curious if `Dot` approach was faster than `Total/@` for large symbolic matrices after reading comments.

```
sqSymMx[m_Symbol, n_Integer?Positive] := 
  Table[Indexed[m, {i, j}], {i, n}, {j, n}];

t = With[{r = sqSymMx[x, #]},
     {#,
      First /@ {AbsoluteTiming[Total /@ r;], 
        AbsoluteTiming[r.ConstantArray[1, {Last@Dimensions@r, 1}];]}
      }] & /@ Range[100, 2000, 100];

opts = Sequence[PlotStyle -> {Gray, LightGray}, 
   PlotLegends -> {Total, Dot}, ImageSize -> Medium, 
   Filling -> {1 -> {{2}, {Red, Green}}}];

Column@Through[{
    ListPlot[#, opts] &,
    ListLogPlot[#, opts] &
    }[Inner[List, t[[All, 1]], #, List] & /@ Transpose@t[[All, 2]]]]
```

[image]

It appears it is even though `Total/@` is faster for small symbolic matrices. This is interesting considering that the `Dot` method also needs to also build its column vector of ones.

---

Well, maybe not. If you swap the order the With then `Dot` is noticeably slower and `Total` is noticeably faster. Some caching of the execution or something I imagine. My kernel savvy is practically non-existent.

Comment: +1 Although I am biased when it comes to using `Total`, I like linear algebra approaches.

Comment: @AntonAntonov It is a shame that it is slightly slower than mapping `Total`.  It is called *Mathematica* after-all.

Comment: `Total` has some very advanced mathematical algorithms in it. (It is not just `Plus@@#&`.) Also, `Total` is expected to be faster than the corresponding matrix operations both sparse and dense. Nevertheless, it would be interesting to compare the timings of `Total` vs. `Dot`, especially for sparse arrays.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Humm.  It seems that `Total/@` is faster for small symbolic matrices but loses its appeal for large ones. See the update. Math wins. :-)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Humm. Maybe not. If you swap the order in the `With` then `Dot` is noticeably slower and `Total` is noticeably faster.